# C - fscanf Mixed Numbers and Static Text

Tags: c, scanf

I am trying to read a file formatted in this general way:

```
Text Description: 12
Description2: 1
More descriptive things: 6
```

And I would like to read the numbers 12, 1, and 6 into variables.

I have tried code like this:

```
fscanf(fptr, "Text Description:%d",&desc1);
fscanf(fptr, "Description2:%d",&desc2);
fscanf(fptr, "More descriptive things:%d",&desc3);
```

But for some reason only the first variable is being populated.  Does anyone know why this is the case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add space at the beginning of the string format to avoid the new line problems

```
fscanf(fptr, " Text Description:%d",&desc1);
fscanf(fptr, " Description2:%d",&desc2);
fscanf(fptr, " More descriptive things:%d",&desc3);
```

Comment: `%d` already consumes all preceding white space. The only `%`s that don't consume whitespace are `%c` and `%[`.

Comment: in that case he has only to add space at the beginning of the string format. Thank you for the remark answer updated

Answer (score 0):

You aren't reading the newline once you've processed the 12, so the other two calls are finding that instead of the string or integer and therefore failing. You can use a space in the next `fscanf` call (which consumes all whitespace characters preceding the string you want to match). Alternatively you can consume it with a call to `fgetc`, as long as each line ends immediately with a linefeed, e.g.

```
fscanf(fptr, "Text Description:%d",&desc1);
fgetc(fptr); // drop the next character
fscanf(fptr, "Description2:%d",&desc2);
```

Dropping all stream input after the integer and up to the next '\n' can be done with a loop instead:

```
while (fgetc(fptr) != '\n')
   ;
```

Comment: I'd add an `&& !feof(fptr)` to the while loop just in case (maybe check for `ferror` too if you're too paranoid ;)

Comment: @Shahbaz: yeah, but I'm assuming this input file is as given. It'd need a lot of checks for unreliable input files.

Comment: Better checking against `EOF`. Calling `feof` with no `EOF` found would be erroneous.

Comment: @Kirilenko, I'm sorry if I'm being too pedantic. I wrote an implementation of `stdio` functions for the Linux kernel, so I've been through the standard on that part a lot. The standard is actually quite easy to follow once you're familiar with it. In case you haven't looked at it, you can find the draft of C11 here: http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf

Comment: @Shahbaz: Don't worry, I really appreciate your comments. I tend to be pedantic too (not in I/O, I confess), although I see I have much much to learn.

Comment: @Kirilenko, I know. I thought I know many languages, but I now know I barely even know C.